# LinkedIn OAuth2 redirect_uri

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

I have a question.
I am trying to get authorization via linkedin with some permissions.
On the list of OAuth 2 redirect URLs I wrote the URL I want the linkedin redirect to, it is a local host url for local testing:

```
http://localhost:9000/account/ExternalLogin.aspx
```

But when I create my instance of CustomLinkedInClient : OAuth2Client, the redirect URL turns to

```
http://localhost:9000/account/ExternalLogin.aspx?__provider__=linkedIn&__sid__=xxx
```

I am not sure what is `__provider__=linkedIn&__sid__=xxx` and I am afraid that redirect_uri doesnt match between the two calls.
If someone can help me I really appreciate it!
Thanks!

This is what I send to linkedin:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_fullprofile&state=linkedIn&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/account/RegisterExternalLogin.aspx?__provider__=linkedIn&__sid__=xxx
```

And show the linkedin login with the permission. But when I try to authenticate with a linkedin user, it  fails!

EDITED:

Here is my request method:

```
    public override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl)
    {

        string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
        }
        string accessToken = this.QueryAccessToken(returnPageUrl, code);
        if (accessToken == null)
        {
            return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
        }
}
```

Then I call QueryAccessToken passing the code was return in the last request:

```
 protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
    {
         var postData = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
         postData.Add(new NameValueCollection
         {
         { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
         { "code", authorizationCode },
         { "client_id", _clientId },
         { "client_secret", _clientSecret },
         { "redirect_uri", returnUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) },
         });

         var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TokenEndpoint);

         webRequest.Method = "POST";
         webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

         using (var s = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
         using (var sw = new StreamWriter(s))
         sw.Write(postData.ToString());

         using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
         {
             var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
             if (responseStream == null)
             return null;

             using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
             {
                 var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                 var json = JObject.Parse(response);
                 var accessToken = json.Value<string>("access_token");
                 return accessToken;
             }
         }

    }
```

but get an error when trying to access to the request:

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

What is could be?
Thanks

EDITED 2:

New request Method:

```
        protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.AppendFormat("client_id={0}", this._clientId);
            postData.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()));
            postData.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", this._clientSecret);
            postData.AppendFormat("&grant_type={0}", "authorization_code");
            postData.AppendFormat("&code={0}", authorizationCode);

            string response = "";
            string accessToken = "";

            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TokenEndpoint);

            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            try
            {

                using (Stream s = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                        sw.Write(postData.ToString());
                }

                using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                JavaScriptSerializer deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var userData = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);

                //var json = JObject.Parse(response);
                accessToken = (string)userData["access_token"];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return accessToken;
}
```

Comment: The redirect URL is supposed to be public accessible as linkedIn should be able to redirect users back to your site.

Comment: So it means I can not test in the localhost? What if I want just redirect to my localhost, is just for testing.

Comment: @ArchiFloyd: Not true. The response URI can be an internal site too, there is no need for the public service to access that site, as long as *you* can access it.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I get an error when I try to access to the request: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Did you read the response stream?

Comment: I see on my GetRequestStream this: Length = 's.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' and 's.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException

Comment: The *response*, not the *request*.

Comment: I can not access to the response because throw an error

Comment: You should probably remove your client ID from the post (as well as other sensitive information), just write "myClientId" instead, people will understand.

Comment: Its not the real ID, just change it...

Comment: Please keep discussing here instead of in chat.

Comment: ok perfect... I dont know what I am doing wrong... :(

Comment: I change the request method for this but the same happens...

Comment: Could someone please check if what I am doing is ok?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes it is true that you can do it like this. What I ment was he should make sure that the URI that is linked is actually located on 127.0.0.1 and not a test server. :)